# Javascript - how to replace all + in a string with a blank space

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have input box on my page which contains strings separated by + such as:

```
this+is+my+string
```

On page load i want to replace all + with a blank. I have tried:

```
var str = $('#MyText1');

str = str.replace(/+/gi, ' ');
```

However i am getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid quantifier
```

Please note my application is using Angular v.1.2.8

Comment: "escape" the plus sign -> `str = str.replace(/\+/gi, ' ');` then it works.

Comment: @davidkonrad - With the above, i am seeing error: Error: str.replace is not a function Is this because i am using Angular?

Comment: have posted an answer, you also forget to extract the value from the input, you just reference the input box itself, and that has no `.replace()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to extract the content of the input box :

```
var str = $('#MyText1').val();
                        ^^^^^
```

now the escape will work :

```
str = str.replace(/\+/gi, ' ');
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/8TKWZ/**

Comment: and, also, he forgets to scape the plus sign :-)

Answer (score 5):

`+` is indeed a quantifier in regular expressions (meaning "1 or more").

You're close with your syntax -- try

```
str = str.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
```

Comment: With the above, i am seeing error: Error: str.replace is not a function Is this because i am using Angular?

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing using a regular expression.  In a regular expression, '+' has special meaning.  However, you don't want that special meaning, you want the literal character.  As such, you must escape the '+'

```
str = str.replace(/\+/gi, ' ');
```